Struggling in client and sever components
import axios from 'axios';
import Image from 'next/image';
export const generateMetadata = async({params}) => { 
try { 
const res = await axios(api url); 
return { title: title, description: Description, } / 

} catch (error) 
{ 
console.error('Error fetching data:', error); 
throw error; // Re-throw the error to propagate it up the call stack. 
} }
async function getSingle(params) 
{ 
try 
{ 
const res = await axios(https://apiurl.com/${params?.slug}.json); 
return res.data; 
} catch (error) 
{ 
console.error('Error fetching data:', error); throw error; // Re-throw the error to propagate it up the call stack. } }
const page = async ({params}) => { 
const data = await getSingle(params)
return ( <>
 <div className='detailImage'>
 <Image width={1000} height={1000} src={image url} alt={title} />
 <div className='detailText'>{title text}</div>
 <div className='detailCross' >
 <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" strokeWidth="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M563.8 512l262.5-312.9c4.4-5.2.7-13.1-6.1-13.1h-79.8c-4.7 0-9.2 2.1-12.3 5.7L511.6 449.8 295.1 191.7c-3-3.6-7.5-5.7-12.3-5.7H203c-6.8 0-10.5 7.9-6.1 13.1L459.4 512 196.9 824.9A7.95 7.95 0 0 0 203 838h79.8c4.7 0 9.2-2.1 12.3-5.7l216.5-258.1 216.5 258.1c3 3.6 7.5 5.7 12.3 5.7h79.8c6.8 0 10.5-7.9 6.1-13.1L563.8 512z"></path>
 </svg>
 </div>
 </div>
 </>
  )
}

export default page


Can anybody please let me know that what's wrong i'm doing here. local is working fine but i'm getting error on routing when i deploy it to production
The console say:
Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.
it is working if i call the API into client component, but i need to fetch the data in server component only for server side rendering

are you calling next api route handler in a server component

Yes, need to render the data at server end

https://nextjs-faq.com/fetch-api-in-rsc

I'm not using my own api, i'm using reddit public api.

Have you made an error.js file?

This error occurs because you're trying to use asynchronous data fetching (getSingle function) inside a server-side rendered component (page function), which is not supported by Server Components in Next.js.
To fix this issue, you should fetch the data in a separate function outside of the component and pass the fetched data as props to your component. Here's how you can refactor your code:
This error occurs because you're trying to use asynchronous data fetching (getSingle function) inside a server-side rendered component (page function), which is not supported by Server Components in Next.js.
To fix this issue, you should fetch the data in a separate function outside of the component and pass the fetched data as props to your component. Here's how you can refactor your code:
`// api.js
import axios from 'axios';
        export async function getSingleData(slug) {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`https://apiurl.com/${slug}.json`);
            return res.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            throw error;
        }
        }

        // pages/[slug].js
        import { getSingleData } from '../api';
        import Image from 'next/image';

        export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
        const data = await getSingleData(params.slug);
        return {
            props: {
            data
            }
        };
        }

        export default function Page({ data }) {
        const { title, imageUrl } = data;

        return (
            <>
            <div className='detailImage'>
                <Image width={1000} height={1000} src={imageUrl} alt={title} />
                <div className='detailText'>{title}</div>
                <div className='detailCross'>
                <svg
                    stroke='currentColor'
                    fill='currentColor'
                    strokeWidth='0'
                    viewBox='0 0 1024 1024'
                    height='1em'
                    width='1em'
                    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                >
                    <path d='M563.8 512l262.5-312.9c4.4-5.2.7-13.1-6.1-13.1h-79.8c-4.7 0-9.2 2.1-12.3 5.7L511.6 449.8 295.1 191.7c-3-3.6-7.5-5.7-12.3-5.7H203c-6.8 0-10.5 7.9-6.1 13.1L459.4 512 196.9 824.9A7.95 7.95 0 0 0 203 838h79.8c4.7 0 9.2-2.1 12.3-5.7l216.5-258.1 216.5 258.1c3 3.6 7.5 5.7 12.3 5.7h79.8c6.8 0 10.5-7.9 6.1-13.1L563.8 512z'></path>
                </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            </>
        );
        }
        `

